# Can we use OR with LIKE predicate in DB2 queries?

Tags: db2

I have a query to select names of employee start with 'y', then my query would be

```
SELECT EMP_NM FROM EMP
WHERE EMP_NM LIKE'Y%'
```

Say for example

> I need to retrieve names of employee
>   names start with both 'y' and 'z', do
>   we have anything to suffice my
>   requirement? It's something like using
>   OR with LIKE, correct?

Your time and responses are highly appreciated.

Comment: So when you executed the query you know how to write but didn't know if worked, what result did you get?

Comment: Hi Ronnis, I tried and got an another question posted in the comment below. Ofcos, he responded back.. lemme try and get back. Thanks for checking on how did the query go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE EMP_NM LIKE 'Y%' OR EMP_NM LIKE 'Z%'
```

or, not sure [if DB2 supports this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db29.doc.sqlref/db2z_likepredicate.htm) (not even sure I have right link to documentation...)

```
WHERE EMP_NM LIKE '[YZ]%'
```

Comment: As you expected, DB2 doesn't support it seems. What happens when we have a multiple strings to be searched using LIKE. say LIKE 'RAJA%' OR 'LIKE 'GBN%''. Do we have a way to address it in DB2. Please let me know if its not clear. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Change the WHERE to a JOIN with LIKE onto a table with all your string expressions?

Comment: I was out of city on a personal vacation. Ofcos, I'm late to respond... lemme try this... Thanks for your interest.

Comment: IBM added support for regular expression SQL functions in Db2 11.1 for Linux, UNIX, and Windows https://www.idug.org/p/bl/et/blogaid=605 The original question on this page (determining if EMP_NM begins with Y or Z) can be handled by calling `REGEXP_LIKE( EMP_NM, '^[YZ]' )`