# DB2 LIKE operator character range

Tags: db2, sql-like

I'm attempting to construct a `LIKE` operator in my query on DB2 that is checking if a varchar is just two digits. I've looked online and it seems like DB2 does not support a character range i.e. [0-9]. I've tried `LIKE '[0-9][0-9]'` and I didn't get an error from DB2, but no rows showed up in my result set from that query when I can see rows that exactly match this through looking at a SELECT * of the same table.

Is there anyway I can replicate this in DB2 if it is indeed true? Is my syntax for the `LIKE` wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [TRANSLATE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000862.html) function is more appropriate for validating an expression that contains a limited number of valid values.

`WHERE TRANSLATE( yourExpressionOrColumn, '000000000', '123456789') = '00'`

Comment: IBM added support for regular expression SQL functions in Db2 11.1 for Linux, UNIX, and Windows https://www.idug.org/p/bl/et/blogaid=605 
The original question on this page (determining if a column has a two-digit value) can be handled by calling `REGEXP_LIKE( yourExpressionOrColumn, '^[0-9][0-9]$' )`

Answer (score 1):

[Found it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5370761/854854). No you cannot and there are no symbols that can represent an OR in `LIKE`.